# Какой знак поставить? Двоеточие, запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, бсп

*Я понять не могу() у вас так много сил?*

Запятая или двоеточие? Можно ли считать "я понять не могу" за вводную конструкцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В БЕССОЮЗНОМ СЛОЖНОМ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИИ](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=148) (Розенталь)

> § 44. Двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении
>
> Между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится двоеточие, если вторая часть (одно или несколько предложений) раскрывает содержание первой части.
>   *Об одном прошу вас: стреляйте скорее* (Л.)...
>   *Я понимаю: вам трудно сейчас сказать о целях, которые преследует литература* (М. Г.).
>
> Перед **прямым вопросом**, включенным в состав бессоюзного сложного предложения, ставится двоеточие: *Спрашивается теперь: что же делало наше общество в последние 20 — 30 лет?* (Добр.); *Одного только я не понимаю: как она могла тебя укусить?* (Ч.).

*Я понять не могу: у вас так много сил?* Не думаю, что в данном предложении "я понять не могу" является вводной конструкцией.

Answer (score 1):

Это тот самый случай, когда выбор знака всецело остаётся за автором и ни один редактор не правомочен этот выбор оспорить. Вы вправе использовать как запятую, так двоеточие или тире. Технически знаки немного повлияют на интонационную фразы, но не изменят её смысла. Этот вопрос уже несколько раз поднимался на форуме. При выборе отталкивайтесь от следующих соображений:

**Запятая**. "Классический" вариант для тех, кто не хочет слишком себя озадачивать. Он подчёркивает подчинительное взаимоотношение частей предложения, хотя в нём и отсутствуют какие-либо союзы, указывающие на это. Близко по функции к вводной конструкции. Сравните: "Я понять не могу" с "Как я понимаю".

**Двоеточие**. Так мы показываем, что вторая часть предложения уточняет первую, даёт конкретику о том, что именно не может понять автор фразы. Обычно двоеточие предваряет часть предложения, которая поясняет, почему именно происходит то, о чём сказано в первой части. Указывает на причину. Это спокойная формулировка.

**Тире**. Сигнализирует об интонационной паузе, присутствующей в этой фразе, и разграничивает два предложения, имеющие свои грамматические основы. Это интонационно более агрессивная форма. Если фраза произнесена с претензией, то тире здесь уместнее.